# Translation of "single-digit millionaire"

Tags: traduction

What's the translation of “single-digit millionaire" in French?

“Single-digit millionaire" in English [designates](https://theintercept.com/2016/10/31/trump-fan-peter-thiel-says-single-digit-millionaires-have-no-effective-access-to-our-legal-system/) an individual whose net worth is between 1M USD and 10M USD.

Comment: https://www.deepl.com/translator → « Millionnaire à un chiffre ». On pourrait dire lorsque l’on entre dans le groupe avec son premier *million* :  « un primo millionnaire ». valable aussi pour *milliard*.

Comment: Je dirais tout simplement « Millionnaire. »

Comment: @Personne thanks, sounds like an automated literal translation: I've never heard it. But I can't find of anything better though.

Comment: @Toto how would you distinguish 1-10M millionaires from 10M+ millionaires? Multimillionaires is still a bit ambiguous.

Comment: À mon sens, la seule distinction qui existe est *Millionnaire* (de 1 à quelques millions) et *multimillionnaire* pour plus de quelques millions, reste à définir la valeur de « *quelques*», disons entre 10 et 50.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt — En France en dira « C’est un parvenu qui nous rebat les oreilles avec son ou ses premiers *millions/milliards* », mais pour rester dans l’esprit du lien cité, DeepL a donné la traduction la plus compréhensible et la plus fidèle à l’esprit initial, de plus elle est tout à fait audible par un natif de l’hexagone.

Answer (score 2):

The closest way to tell it in French would be;

"Il a en banques dans les sept chiffres" (X XXX XXX (7 numbers))
or
"Il gagne dans les sept chiffres"

My last example is less precise as it can mean he earn that by year, or a win he raffled in the lotterie, while my first exemple mean he got that inside his pockets.

Millionnaire and Multimillionnaire could be used, but the term *multi* is not used the same way for everyone so it lack precision.

The lack of precision is like; "Il est riche" versus "Il est riche comme crésus". (the perception is not the same for everyone)

*A note; The expression is used in French Canada, I can't tell if it's universal or not*

You can see an example of the usage [there on radio-canada.ca](https://ici.radio-canada.ca/nouvelle/459518/banques-bonus-usa);

"Citant des dirigeants de banques, le journal soutient que certains bonus pourraient atteindre ***« six, sept, voire huit chiffres »***, selon les personnes. Selon les dirigeants rencontrés, le public américain pourrait être « abasourdi » des montants offerts."

Comment: Can you assert that this is metropolitan French as well (I guess it is at least Canadian)?

Comment: @LPH It's an expression used in Canada, but is it used in France ? for that I don't know. To give an example; https://ici.radio-canada.ca/nouvelle/459518/banques-bonus-usa; *"Citant des dirigeants de banques, le journal soutient que certains bonus pourraient atteindre « six, sept, voire huit chiffres », selon les personnes. Selon les dirigeants rencontrés, le public américain pourrait être « abasourdi » des montants offerts."*

Comment: Inclure ces précisions dans votre réponse serait une bonne chose ; on saurait ainsi en la lisant qu'il est possible que ce terme ne soit pas connu en France. Personnellement je ne l'ai jamais entendu et personne jusqu'à présent ne l'a mentionné dans les commentaires.

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Comment: Il y a une autre différence culturelle: en Europe (pas seulement en France), dans la presse, les comparatifs, les conversations, les négotiations salariales, on a tendance à donner les chiffres de salaires mensuels tandis qu'en Amérique du Nord (et donc au Quéebc), je pense qu'on parlera plutôt de salaire annuel comme référence. Donc, en France, si on dit *il gagne X euro* sans précision.on pensera plutôt à un chiffre de salaire mensuel.

Answer (score 0):

In informal language, it is common to use the word *peser* to refer to someone's (large) fortune.

> Jeff Bezos pèse 180 milliards de dollars US.

Based on that, you could imagine some turns of phrases such as

> Ces personnes pèsent chacune entre 1 et 10 millions.